# 404 when multiple dots on url

Tags: regex, reactjs, apache, http, url

I´m working on a React project.
When I try to load some local route like '/example.2.2/hello.js`im getting 404, if I do the same changing the folder and the path '/example22/hello.js' it is working additionally if I host it https://example.com/example.2.2/hello.ja it is working.

I'm using apache server to virtualhost, windows 10.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Node has problems hosting content with dots(periods) on the folder name on windows platform, I just changed package.json